# How is the Tempest Trials bonus applied?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Normally, bonus units will give you the bonus points right after a level, such as in the Arena. However, the Tempest Trials force you to do up to 7 fights in a row with up to 4 different teams. I spent the entirety of today raising a level 1 4☆ Nowi into a level 40 5☆ unit to try and reap the 40% bonus since she's a current bonus ally.

[image: bonus allies]

The team she was on (Team 1) lost on map 4 of 5 and I was ultimately unable to win on map 5. However, I noticed that I was given more points than a loss should have awarded me. Does the bonus ally simply need to be on *any* team to get the bonus for all maps or does the bonus only apply to maps that that unit was present on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the bonus ally simply need to be on any team to get the bonus for all maps or does the bonus only apply to maps that that unit was present on?

The bonus ally in Tempest Trials only needs to be on 1 of your teams for you to get the full 1.4x or 1.2x bonus.

I can confirm this is how it works as for the last Tempest trail I had my [Faye](https://fireemblem.gamepress.gg/hero/faye) (who gave a 40% bonus in the last Tempest trial) on the first team with random other heroes, which sometimes got past the first map but often simply died without beating even the first map, then I proceeded to finish the map with my main team.

Even when the team with Faye did not clear a single map, at the end of the trial I got the 1.4x bonus.

Comment: This is right. I figured this out a while ago myself, but I forgot to post an answer